# React lazy loading: how to control what goes into chunks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, code-splitting

Background: I don't have much experience with lazy loading in react and i have to maintain a project that is using it.

The problem is that when loading page "A" directly the styles are different than when loading page "B" and then navigating to page "A".

The reason is that the loaded chunks differ and clearly page "B" chunks contain some styles that are overriding page "A" styles.

This is a standard `create-react-app` project.
For reference the structure of the app is something like this

```
const PageA = React.lazy(() => import('./routes/PageA'))
const PageB = React.lazy(() => import('./routes/PageB'))

export const Content: React.FC = () => (
  <Suspense>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={PageA} />
      <Route exact path="/b" component={PageB} />
    </Switch>
  </Suspense>
)
```

So i'm wondering, how do i control what goes into each chunk?

If i don't have that level of control then what's the exact logic used to split the code into chunks?

Can you point me to any in-depth document that really explains everything i need to know about code-splitting + lazy loading; i read a few articles on medium plus the react docs but i cannot find the answers i'm looking for like: what the actual code-splitting algorithm looks like and how can i tame it.

Also i guess the case in which one chunk overrides styles to another chunk is due to some bad practice happening in the app, any idea what i should look for and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**:
I found where the rogue styles were coming from.
In a totally unrelated utility file i found these two imports

```
import '@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css'
import '@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css'
```

and of course PageB was importing the utility file and PageA wasn't

I think this kind of css import (that incidentally overrides a bunch of element selectors like `body`) manages to confuse the code splitting algorithm. Still i believe the more generic questions are still valid.

Comment: does component PageA or PageB contain styles? can you show source code if possible.

Comment: @AyyappaGollu yes they contain separate style files but i found the issue, see the update for more details

Comment: This becomes problem in general as well. One way to avoid this is using [css-modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/)

Comment: @Sunil yep, css-modules are implemented by default in `create-react-app` and are used in this project, the problem was that it was importing directly css from an external source (so clearly non-module css)